# How to Replace value of string in file with dictionary key-value using python script

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I replace a string in file with dictionary value using python:

I have a file with content as below:

```
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-496"} 580
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-497"} 620
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-498"} 630
```

Now I have a dictionary as below:

```
dict1={'feed-496':'high','feed-497':'low','feed-498':'medium'}
```

How can I replace 'feed-496' in file with key value from above dictionary using python script.

Comment: `readlines()` and regular expressions are your best friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace certain strings in a text file use .replace(wrongelement, rightelement)

in.txt:

> Hello and welcome to pyton.

Code:

```
fin = open("in.txt", "rt")
fout = open("out.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
    fout.write(line.replace('pyton', 'python'))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

out.txt:

> Hello and welcome to python.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
dict1={'feed-496':'high','feed-497':'low','feed-498':'medium'}
fin = open("in.txt", "rt")
fout = open("out.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
    for key in dict1:
        fout.write(line.replace(key, dict1[key]))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: When I use above code I see values are getting modified; But I see multiple entries in the fout; Say as below.

```No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="high"} 580
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-496"} 580
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-497"} 620
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="low"} 620
No.of documents inserted in collection{col_id="feed-497"} 620```

I am not sure why additional lines are adding after replacing the value

Answer (score 1):

Approach with built-ins:

```py
# file_contents = file.read() or similar, as long as it's a string.

for find, replacement in dict1.items():
    file_contents.replace(find, replacement)
```

Note that replacements in this case should never have also appear in the dictionary keys or they will end up being replaced by later iterations of the loop.

Alternatively, with regex:

```py
import re

# ...

# Make a function that picks what to replace with.
def feed_level(match_obj):
    # Use the capture group (see regex below) as key for the dictionary.
    return dict1[match_obj.group(0)]

re.sub(r'col_id="(.*?)"', feed_level, file_contents)
```

This does not have the same limitation as the other approach above. Both possibilities allow you to expand the dictionary at any time without having to modify this code when you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

dict1={'feed-496':'high','feed-497':'low','feed-498':'medium'}

with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                         #Iterate Each Line
        key = re.search(r'\"(.*?)\"', line)     #Search for key between Quotes
        if key:
            print(line.replace(key.group(1), dict1.get(key.group(1), key.group(1))))    #Replace Value
```

Comment: Hw can we make above code to replace file rather than priniting on stdout

Comment: Append the lines to a list and write the list back to the file